# Efeito de aumentar e diminuir tamanho de bordas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Encontrei em um site um exemplo de um campo **apenas** aumentando a borda, segue o GIF abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. Gostaria de saber se consigo além de aumentar, diminuir o tamanho da borda de um elemento html na chamada do mesmo evento?
2. Seria possível realizar esse efeito(expandir/diminuir) o px da borda **ao carregar a tela** sem que haja algum evento vínculado no elemento, por exemplo, um determinado input ao carregar a tela ficar expandindo e diminuindo a borda em um efeito constante sem fim.

Comment: Não entendi direito vc que mudar a espessura da borda enquanto a página estiver carregando? Tipo no loar da página vc vai diminuindo o border? E no input vc quer que ele tenha um border-bottom que fique aumentando e diminuindo a espessura sem parar como se estivesse "pulsando"? Ficou meio confuso as coisas que quer fazer... Vc quer que a borda do btn cresça para dentro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu não sei direito se entendi o que vc quer, mas em vez de usar `border` vc pode usar o `box-shadow` com valores como `spread-radius` e `inset` para fazer esses efeitos. Pro `.btn` basta usar um `transition` junto `:hover`, já pro `input` vc precisa fazer um `@keyframes` `alternate` para fica pulsando.

**OBS:** No `.btn` coloquei uma "borda" de cada cor, para vc ver que uma cresce para dentro `inset`, e outra para fora:

```css
.btn {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red,
                      0 0 0 1px blue;
    transition: box-shadow 500ms linear;
}
.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px red,
                      0 0 0 4px blue;
}

.glow {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 red;
    animation: glow-box 1s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes glow-box {
    to {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px red;
    }
}
```

```html
<br>

<a class="btn" href="#">
    <span>Meu BTN</span>
</a>

<br><br><br>

<input class="glow" type="text">
```

Aqui tem a documentação completa da Mozilla sobre o `box-shadow`, deve te interessar: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Essa pergunta sobre múltiplas bordas em um elemento pode te interessar tb: [Como ter mais de uma Borda em um Elemento com CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336821/como-ter-mais-de-uma-borda-em-um-elemento-com-css)

Comment: @AndréFilipe tranquilo garoto tmj

Comment: Corrigindo, os seus exemplos foram os que sanaram minha dúvida. Agradecido Hugo, abraços!